# Java SFTP error when using org.apache.commons.vfs.FileObject.copyFrom()

Tags: java, apache, file, sftp, vfs

I am currently using the Apache VFS to copy files from source folder to destination folder.

To copy the file from Source to Destination , i am using the call as follows:
FileObject fileSrc = manager.resolveFile(********Source file_details****);
            FileObject fileDest = manager.resolveFile(********Destaintion file_details****);

```
fileDest.copyFrom(fileSrc, Selectors.SELECT_SELF);
```

The above call is resulting in the below error:
org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Could not copy "source file" to "Destiantion".
.
.
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Could not close the output stream for file
.
.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 4: Transfer failed possibly due to access restrictions.

However in the same class, i am using the below call to move it a archive location as follows:
int moveIndicator = sftpClientForMove.moveFile(file, source folder, file, archive location);

This call executes fine without any issues and the file is copied.

Can you please help me why the exception is being thrown in the first call.

Comment: Thanks , i have edited the question.

Comment: I missed it the first time, now the tag has been updated.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl , thanks for pointing these out, it would be of great help if you can help me with this issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show all of the relevant code from your program. Ideally, you would show us a small, self-contained program which demonstrates your problem. Posting one or two lines out of context and describing the rest isn't very useful.